# How to omit something from a loop?

Tags: c#

```
        for (int k = 0; k < 32;k++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
            {

                double Score = (user0[k] * user0[j] + user1[k] * user1[j] + user2[k] * user2[j] + user3[k] * user3[j] + user4[k] * user4[j] + user5[k] * user5[j] + user6[k] * user6[j] +
                    user7[k] * user7[j] + user8[k] * user8[j] + user9[k] * user9[j] + user10[k] * user10[j] + user11[k] * user11[j] + user12[k] * user12[j] + user13[k] * user13[j] + user14[k] * user14[j] + user15[k] * user15[j] + user16[k] * user16[j] + user17[k] * user17[j] +
                    user18[k] * user18[j] + user19[k] * user19[j] + user20[k] * user20[j] + user21[k] * user21[j] + user22[k] * user22[j] + user23[k] * user23[j] +
                    user24[k] * user24[j] + user25[k] * user25[j] + user26[k] * user26[j] + user27[k] * user27[j] + user28[k] * user28[j] + user29[k] * user29[j] +
                    user30[k] * user30[j] + user31[k] * user31[j]) / ((Math.Sqrt(user0[k] * user0[k] + user1[k] * user1[k] + user2[k] * user2[k] + user3[k] * user3[k] + user4[k] * user4[k] + user5[k] * user5[k] + user6[k] * user6[k] + user7[k] * user7[k] + user8[k] * user8[k] + user9[k] * user9[k] +
                    user10[k] * user10[k] + user11[k] * user11[k] + user12[k] * user12[k] + user13[k] * user13[k] + user14[k] * user14[k] + user15[k] * user15[k] + user16[k] * user16[k] + user17[k] * user17[k] +
                    user18[k] * user18[k] + user19[k] * user19[k] + user20[k] * user20[k] + user21[k] * user21[k] + user22[k] * user22[k] + user23[k] * user23[k] + user24[k] * user24[k] +
                    user25[k] * user25[k] + user26[k] * user26[k] + user27[k] * user27[k] + user28[k] * user28[k] + user29[k] * user29[k] + user30[k] * user30[k] + user31[k] * user31[k])) * (Math.Sqrt(user0[j] * user0[j] + user1[j] * user1[j] + user2[j] * user2[j] + user3[j] * user3[j] +
                    user4[j] * user4[j] + user5[j] * user5[j] + user6[j] * user6[j] + user7[j] * user7[j] + user8[j] * user8[j] + user9[j] * user9[j] + user10[j] * user10[j] + user11[j] * user11[j] +
                    user12[j] * user12[j] + user13[j] * user13[j] + user14[j] * user14[j] + user15[j] * user15[j] + user16[j] * user16[j] + user17[j] * user17[j] +
                    user18[j] * user18[j] + user19[j] * user19[j] + user20[j] * user20[j] + user21[j] * user21[j] + user22[j] * user22[j] + user23[j] * user23[j] + user24[j] * user24[j]
                    + user25[j] * user25[j] + user26[j] * user26[j] + user27[j] * user27[j] + user28[j] * user28[j] + user29[j] * user29[j] + user30[j] * user30[j] + user31[j] * user31[j])));


                if (Score > simScore)
                {
                    simScore = Score;
                }


            }
```

If I wanted to have the loop not calculated when k=j, how do I go about doing this?
My code calculations are messed up when the loop is calculated when k=j since it will take the greatest value from 32 results and if the k=j loop is calculated, the greatest value will always be the j=k case.

Comment: What the hell is that code doing?

Comment: Code like user1+user2+user3... usually looks like it should be an array of users, and then you can use a nested loop.

Comment: Wow, that is one ridiculous line of code.  I any single line of code ever begged for refactoring, this is it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use [`continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx), in your loop:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 32; k++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
    {
        if (k == j)
            continue;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This restarts the loop back at the top right?
And moving j to the next value? (Going from j=1 to j=2?)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that is OCD, but you forced me to show you this:

```
double[,] user = new double[32,32];

for (int k = 0; k < 32; k++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
    {
        if (k == j)
            continue;
        double Score = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {

                Score = (user[i,k] * user[i,j])  /  Math.Sqrt(user[i,k] * user[i,k]) *  Math.Sqrt(user[i,j] * user[i,j] );

                if (Score > simScore)
                {
                    simScore = Score;
                }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use [Continue](http://www.dotnetperls.com/continue) :**

[Continue](http://www.dotnetperls.com/continue) alters control flow. It is often found in loop bodies. It allows you to skip the execution of the rest of the iteration. It jumps immediately to the next iteration in the loop. This keyword is often useful in while-loops.

```
while (true)
    {
        // Get a random number.
        int value = random.Next();
        // If number is divisible by two, skip the rest of the iteration.
        if ((value % 2) == 0)
        {
        continue;
        }
        // If number is divisible by three, skip the rest of the iteration.
        if ((value % 3) == 0)
        {
        continue;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Not divisible by 2 or 3: {0}", value);
        // Pause.
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
```